# Algebra related puzzle

Tags: algebra, find-the-order

I have got a puzzle as a Christmas present from a friend of mine and I have managed to solve it while skipping this part, but I would still be interested in how this represents the information that I have figured out by myself as well.

[image: The piece of paper I have.]

The only instruction for it in the accompanying letter was this: "You will require some algebra."

What I've also got was a crossword and clues for the missing words. After getting all the words I arranged them into the crossword through trial and error, and after solving their order I came back to this piece of paper.

What I know right now is that the correct order was `3, 23, 10, 13, 20, 24, 16, 8, 12, 9, 14, 11, 21, 15, 2, 5, 22, 6, 19, 4, 7, 18, 17` which, as I have noticed, corresponds to the sequence that can be read by removing the `15` from every pair and then going left-to-right, top-to-bottom in a row major consecutive manner starting from the `(3, 15)` entry, inserting `15` at the end and then wrapping around.

I have also noticed that the pairs are ordered such that the lower number is always on the left and as I have already mentioned, the number `15` is present in every pair. (Also, there are only 22 pairs for 23 words.)

The only thing I have found to use this parenthesis pair notation is for denoting the greatest common divisor of two numbers, but that doesn't really seem to be of much help here.

Comment: Can you describe a bit more how the you define the order of the crossword clues? Also, did you deduce the correct order of the numbers using the crossword?

Comment: If you solved the puzzle you were given without reference to this part, can it be reverse-engineered from the solution? Or was it a red herring?

Comment: The reverse-engineering process led me to noticing the things I've mentioned in the end of the post, but those still don't clarify to me the mathematical operator I should've used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've posted this same thing on reddit's [/r/puzzles](https://www.reddit.com/r/puzzles) as well and a helpful commenter (who goes by the username [/u/Ibot02](https://www.reddit.com/user/Ibot02)) managed to crack the meaning behind the numbers there. The [answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/puzzles/comments/bmqjid/algebra_related_puzzle/en3t7sn?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) is as follows:

> Discussion: This looks to me like a permutation, written as the
>   composition of transpositions.
>
> In this way, (2 15) represents the permutation that swaps 2 and 15
>   (and does not change anything else). (2 15) (5 15) is then the
>   composition of two such transpositions, so you'd swap 2 and 15, then 5
>   and 15, resulting in the permutation that maps 2 to 5, 5 to 15 and 15
>   to 2, also written (2 5 15). (Composition is sometimes written the
>   other way around, but this is consistent with the result you found).
>
> In the end, putting everything together, you'd get (2 5 22 6 19 4 7 18
>   17 3 23 10 13 20 24 16 8 12 9 14 11 21 15), or (3 23 10 13 20 24 16 8
>   12 9 14 11 21 15 2 5 22 6 19 4 7 18 17) (these are the same
>   permutation since the notation is cyclical - you'd map every element
>   to the next in the cycle, wrapping around).
>
> This represents the permutation that maps 2 to 5, 3 to 23, 4 to 7…
>
> I hope this isn't too confusing, if you still have questions or some
>   of this is unclear, please ask.